# After a kernel update, the external microphone isn't detected anymore

Tags: sound, kernel, microphone

I used to use Debian 11 on my computer. After a newer kernel was installed, the external P2 cable microphone wasn't detected anymore and I had to use an older kernel for it to be recognized. Today I use Ubuntu 20.04, and the same problem persists. I had to install the kernel 5.11.0-34 for it to work. If I use the most recent kernel, 5.13.0-35, the external microphone isn't detected anymore.

Comment: The HWE kernel 5.11 isn't patched for security flaws as it's EOL with HWE having moved to 5.13.  If you're having issues with the HWE kernel, why not switch to the GA kernel stack?  (Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices - GA + HWE; GA the most stable & default for server installs; HWE for desktop installs.. not including OEM options).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @guiverc I followed the procedure of the page above ([wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)) and installed the kernel 5.4.0-104. After booting to this kernel, the problem still persists. I think that maybe an older version of this same kernel may work, because the kernel 5.11.0-46 doesn't work, but the 5.11.0-34 works.

Comment: I'm busy currently; but given you have a working kernel & *patched* kernel that doesn't work; I'd be exploring launchpad.net for bugs that fit your issue; you can click "affects me too" as you're describing a *regression* I suspect; and bug reports often have *workarounds* or *tips* that are useful in resolving the issue.  Though given 5.4 is a much older kernel (and uses different kernel modules (ie. *drivers*)) it maybe unrelated to kernel & due to something else you've done (possibly in the last session before issue occurred). Me I'd likely test *live* media on box; but 5.11 kernels are EOL

Comment: Just for completeness, I tested various 5.11.0 kernels, and the versions 5.11.0-34, 5.11.0-36, 5.11.0-37 and 5.11.0-38 works as expected. The versions 5.11.0-40, 5.11.0-41, 5.11.0-43, 5.11.0-44 and 5.11.0-46 doesn't work.

Comment: If you're off-line you can use the 5.11 kernels, but given they're *unsupported* and *unpatched* for security flaws; you should not use them on any box connected to the internet.  Ubuntu 20.04's supported kernels are 5.4 (GA) & 5.13 (HWE) plus OEM options